# How can I extract all div that have a specificl element in it, that it's not class, span, a or li?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract from the a webpage which has many of the following divs (obviously all with different data, except for the initial part):

```html
<div data-asin="B007R2E578" data-index="0" 
  class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28">
  <div class="sg-col-inner">
```

All those divs, start identically with: `<div data-asin=`

I'm trying to extract all of them with the find_all function from Beautifulsoup:

```
structure = soup.find_all('div','data-asin=')
```

However it always return an empty list.

I don't want to use regex.

Is there any function in BeautifulSoup that can get all those divs?

Comment: Do you want the data-asin itself or the content of divs that have data-asin

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, I'm currently looking to extract from the entire html exclusively all the divs that starts with : <div data-asin=  , without any other divs that does not start specifically like the one described. This is a typical url from which I am extracting the data: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=iron&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use CSS selector `div[data-asin]` (select all `<div>` where `data-asin` attribute is present):

```
data = '''<div data-asin="B007R2E578" data-index="0"
  class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28">
  <div class="sg-col-inner">
   SOME DATA
  </div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for div in soup.select('div[data-asin]'):
    print(div['data-asin'], div.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
B007R2E578 SOME DATA
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

EDIT: To get some data from Amazon:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=iron&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')

for div in soup.select('div[data-asin]'):
    print(div['data-asin'])
    if div.select_one('.a-price'):
        print(div.select_one('.a-price ').get_text('|',strip=True).split('|')[0])
    if div.select_one('.a-text-normal'):
        print(div.select_one('.a-text-normal').text)
```

Prints:

```
B004ILTH1K
$62.81

Rowenta DW5080 1700-Watt Micro Steam Iron Stainless Steel Soleplate with Auto-Off, 400-Hole, Brown

B00OL5P1G8
$21.99

Sunbeam Steam Master 1400 Watt Mid-size Anti-Drip Non-Stick Soleplate Iron with Variable Steam control and 8' Retractable Cord, Black/Blue, GCSBCL-202-000

...etc.
```

Comment: Hi Andrey,  that actually extract the content, is there anyway to extract the entire div from the html, not just the content? Thanks

Comment: @AmatoIlCiabattaro What do you mean entire div? In loop you have variable `div` which you can query for additional required info. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the div tags and then do a list comprehension that will put that atrribute value into a list, if it has that attribute:

```
html = '''<div data-asin="B007R2E578" data-index="0" 
  class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28">
  <div class="sg-col-inner">'''



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div')

a_list = [ div['data-asin'] for div in divs if div.has_attr('data-asin')]
```

Comment: Hi @chitown88 , that actually extract the content, therefore the asin, is there anyway to extract the entire div from the html, not just the content? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This gives you all divs then filter

$(‘:div’).each(function(){

Var ele = $(this);

});